# InApp Billing version 3 to version 5. BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS. codes not working

Tags: java, android-studio, kotlin, in-app-subscription

I tried all the answers on the internet, but nothing works, if anyone has a solution for this, will be really helpful for my application. I'm having a problem migrating the **Google Play billing library** from Version 3 to 5. First of all, I'm not really good with in-app billing. some of the codes are depreciated and not working anymore. some answers from the internet are confusing

I'm getting errors when I add

```java
if (purchase.getProducts().equals(sku)) {
    return true;
} else {
    return false;
}
```

it says "Cannot return a value from a method with void result type"

Then (V3.0.3, worked first).

```java
public boolean isSubscribedToSubscriptionItem(String sku) {
    if (skuListSubscriptionsList != null) {
        Purchase.PurchasesResult result = billingClient.queryPurchases(BillingClient.SkuType.SUBS);

        if (result.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK && result.getPurchasesList() != null) {
            for (Purchase purchase : result.getPurchasesList()) {
                if (purchase.getSku().equals(sku)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Now (V5.1.0, Some errors).

```java
public boolean isSubscribedToSubscriptionItem(String sku) {
    if (skuListSubscriptionsList != null) {
        billingClient.queryPurchasesAsync(
            QueryPurchasesParams.newBuilder()
                .setProductType(BillingClient.ProductType.SUBS)
                .build(),
            new PurchasesResponseListener() {
                @Override
                public void onQueryPurchasesResponse(BillingResult billingResult, List<Purchase> purchases) {
                    if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK&&purchases != null) {
                        for (Purchase purchase : purchases) {
                            // ERROR : Cannot return a value from a method with void result type. What to write here ?
                            if (purchase.getProducts().equals(sku)) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }

    return false;
}
```

These codes are in my splash activity (kt)

```java
override fun displayErrorMessage(message: String?) {
    when {
        message.equals("done") -> {
            AppSettings.isUserPaid =
                billingClass!!.isSubscribedToSubscriptionItem(AppSettings.one_month_subscription_id) ||
                billingClass!!.isSubscribedToSubscriptionItem(AppSettings.three_month_subscription_id) ||
                billingClass!!.isSubscribedToSubscriptionItem(AppSettings.one_year_subscription_id)

            startMainActivity()
        }

        message.equals("error") -> {
            AppSettings.isUserPaid = false;
            startMainActivity()
        } else -> {
            AppSettings.isUserPaid = false;
            startMainActivity()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you are trying to get the ProductId from the Purchase object returned from google play when the user has done purchasing your product.

Please note that This `getSku()`  method is deprecated. Use `getProducts()` instead.

read more: https://developer.android.com/reference/com/android/billingclient/api/Purchase

`getProducts()`  - Returns the product Ids.
The trick is to use `.get(index)` on the list.

Check the example

```java
void verifySubPurchase(Purchase purchases) {
    AcknowledgePurchaseParams acknowledgePurchaseParams = AcknowledgePurchaseParams
            .newBuilder()
            .setPurchaseToken(purchases.getPurchaseToken())
            .build();

    billingClient.acknowledgePurchase(acknowledgePurchaseParams, billingResult -> {
        if (billingResult.getResponseCode() == BillingClient.BillingResponseCode.OK) {
           
 String productId = purchases.getProducts().get(0); /// this one gets the product Id
           
 String purchaseToken = purchases.getPurchaseToken(); /// this one gets the purchase token
        }
    });
}
```